# Apache accept CNAME redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system

I have a domain, let's say `mydomain.com`. I'd like to redirect `www.mydomain.com` to the naked domain, `mydomain.com`. So I set up the following DNS. (The IP is just for show)

```
A        mydomain.com    192.168.0.1
CNAME    www             mydomain.com
```

What happens though, is that Apache serves my default site (which is empty), rather than the `mydomain` site. Since I'm hosting multiple domains, I have:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
/etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain
/etc/apache2/sites-available/myOtherDomain
/etc/apache2/sites-available/yetAnother
```

The start of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mydomain` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin sample@email.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com
```

What's wrong with this setup that's it's not redirecting `www.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com`? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you check if the CNAME-record is already working and resolving (using commands like `host` or `nslookup`)? Did you also make sure that there's no other DNS A record for the www-subdomain or perhaps a wildcard A-record (*.mydomain.com)?

Comment: They resolve just fine... there are no wildcard A records or any other subdomain records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache itself won't redirect for you.. You'd have to use something like mod_rewrite to do that

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Edited for regex syntax.

Comment: But the CNAME record is supposed to send `www.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com`. It's an http level redirect

Comment: That's not how standard dns works.. it might be your provider doing it.

Comment: The CNAME record only redirects DNS lookups to another DNS record, it doesn't affect anything else. DNS will only tell the browser which IP hosts the site, the browser then makes to the request to server asking for the site you put in the address bar (in this case with www.) You will still need to configure Apache correctly so it knows what pages to display to the use or to redirect them as above

Answer (score 0):

Did a little reading up on [Virtual Hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) and found I could do this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin sample@email.com
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com www.mydomain.com
```

which makes it work. Only problem is that the `www` remains in the address bar, rather than a redirect.

Comment: If this is working and the `www` remains in the address bar, this is a sign that your CNAME record is not working but there is an A-record for `www`, otherwise the subdomain could not be resolved. Again, what's the output of `host www.mydomain.com` ?

Comment: @etagenklo `host www.mydomain.com`:
www.mydomain is an alias for mydomain.com.
mydomain.com has address 192.68.0.1
mydomain.com mail is handled by 10 mail.mydomain.com.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck currently. If `www.mydomain.com` is resolved to `mydomain.com` via CNAME (what is done according to your `host` command), this should be exactly the same as opening `mydomain.com` directly, so please excuse my stupid questions: Did you issue the `host www.mydomain.com` command on the same machine you`re trying to open the site from (Explanation: If not, maybe they're using different DNS resolvers and the one on the client machine doesn't know the CNAME yet)? Is opening `mydomain.com` on the client definitely opening `mydomain.com` and not also the default vhost?

Comment: @etagenklo I get exactly the same result if I do it from a different machine. It was resolving to the default site until I added `www.mydomain.com` to the `ServerAlias` directive.